# Am I accessing undefined on my multidimensional array? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined

Tags: javascript

How does accessing of multi-dimensional arrays work on undefined values?

What is up with my 3rd line?

```
  var board = [

            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1]
        ];

        console.log(board[0][0]);  // 0
        console.log(board[0][-1]); // undefined, What's going on here and why? 
        console.log(board[-1][1]);  // uncaught typerror: cannot read property -1 of undefined - Why is this error thrown?
```

Comment: Just food for thought: You can also represent a multidimensional array like follows. `var board = {}; board[[0,0]] = 0; board[[0,1]] = 1;` This results in `board` being `{'0,0':0,'0,1':1}`.

Comment: @TimothyShields: No, better not (for various reasons). And don't confuse newbies with that!

Comment: @Bergi I've only used JS lightly, for small amounts of browser code. If it's something you can say concisely in a comment (or point to a link), for what reasons is it bad? I haven't ever actually used it - just thought of it on the spot.

Comment: @TimothyShields: No link, but: `board` is not an array (slower), it has no dimensions, and when accessing `board[[0,1]]` you implicitly stringify `[0,1]` to `"0,1"`, which is rather confusing and can lead to wrong beliefs. Of course I'm not denying there might be cases where a structure like that can't be useful, but only with careful consideration.

Comment: @Bergi Ok, thanks, even though I was aware of all those. :) For something like a sparse vector or matrix it might make sense, but it seems like for a dense multidimensional array this is not good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no "real" multidimensional arrays in javascript. What you have is just an array of arrays.

Accessing a non-existing property of an inner one (your second example) yields `undefined`.
Accessing a non-existing property of an outer one (your third example) yields `undefined` as well, but you expect to always get an inner array - on which you access property `0`, which throws an exception when it is `undefined`.

Apart from that, never access negative-integer properties on arrays, and if possible don't access indices beyond the length of the array.

Comment: So if I'm checking a board for each value and I need to check to see the neighbor (top-left, top, top-right, etc)  is in-bound, what strategy can I use for this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'access property 0'?

Comment: Test whether the index number itself is in-bound, not whether the property exists. E.g. `x>=0 && x<Xdim && y>=0 && y<Ydim`

Comment: `arr[0]` is a [property access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with the name `0` - just like `obj["value"]`. Arrays are no different from objects in that regard in JavaScript.

Comment: So basically on my third line I'm trying to get the value of this - undefined["someProperty"]?

Comment: Yes, it tries to evaluate `undefined[1]`

Answer (score 0):

On your second line:

`board[0] -> [0,0,0]`

So by doing `board[0][-1]`, you're saying, "Give me element -1 of `[0,0,0]`", which is undefined.

On your third line:

`board[-1] -> undefined`

So by doing `board[-1][1]`, you're saying, "Give me element 1 of `undefined`." Since something that is undefined has no properties, this throws an error.